# Change ggboxplot box outline colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I add black outlines to boxplot bars? If I specify color="black" the text goes on top of each other. I would also like to change the color of the text to black

Data:

```
COUNTRY  ACTUAL    YEAR 
<chr>    <<dbl>    <dbl>   
1 U.S.A.  9.42     1996     
2 U.S.A.  208      1998  
3 U.S.A.  454.     1996  
4 U.S.A.  21.2     1996  
5 U.S.A.  566      1997  
6 Mexico  370.     1995  
7 U.S.A.  845.     1996  
8 Canada  492      1998  
9 U.S.A. 1352.     1998  
10 U.S.A.  103.    1996 
...
```

Code:

```
df %>% 
  select(YEAR, COUNTRY, ACTUAL) %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = as.factor(YEAR)) %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY, YEAR) %>% 
  ggsummarystats(
    ., x = c("COUNTRY"), y = c("ACTUAL"),
    palette=custom_pal,
    ggfunc = ggboxplot,
    color="YEAR",
    fill = "YEAR", 
    summaries = c("n", "mean", "median", "min", "max")
  )
```

Produced picture

[image: Example]

If I edit

```
color=rep("black", 12)
```

Then the picture produced looks like this:
[image: Error]

Which looks good otherwise but the summary statistics are stacked on top of each other and R gives warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (color %in% names(data) & is.null(add.params$color)) add.params$color <- color :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (color %in% colnames(df)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Remove `color="YEAR"`?

Comment: Results in same picture as color=rep("black", 12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the color of two plots separately after assigning the output to an object, let us call it `p`. Changing `p$main.plot` changes the plot outlines and error bars, and changing `p$summary.plot` would change the text color.

```r
p <- df %>% 
    select(YEAR, COUNTRY, ACTUAL) %>% 
    mutate(YEAR = as.factor(YEAR)) %>%
    group_by(COUNTRY, YEAR) %>% 
    ggsummarystats(
        ., x = c("COUNTRY"), y = c("ACTUAL"),
        palette=custom_pal,
        ggfunc = ggboxplot,
        color="YEAR",
        fill = "YEAR", 
        summaries = c("n", "mean", "median", "min", "max")
    )

n <- length(unique(df$YEAR))
p$main.plot <- p$main.plot + scale_color_manual(values=rep("black", n))
p$summary.plot <- p$summary.plot + scale_color_manual(values=rep("black", n))
p
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. You wouldn't know how to change the summary statistics to uppercase by any chance?

Comment: You could do `p$summary.plot$layers[[1]]$data$y <- toupper(p$summary.plot$layers[[1]]$data$y)` (or `p$summary.plot$layers[[1]]$data$y <- tools::toTitleCase(p$summary.plot$layers[[1]]$data$y)` to capitalize the first letter only)